# Getting Sencha Touch Working in PlayBook Simulator?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, vmware, blackberry-playbook, ripple

I have been running Sencha Touch Webworks playbook application successfully. I tested on riple and also on VMware and everything is cool. However, I started getting a white screen after the splash screen and no erroron log and really frustrated. Any efforts to set up again futile and dont know what to do, this was almost over, I had even sent version 1 to appworld but now I cant debug. Funny enough is that in ripple, eerything runs fine as expected.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Web Inspector? It's a great tool for debugging issues just like this one. For more information go to

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html

Tip: Once you have everything up and running, CTRL+R in the Console window of Web Inspector will restart the application (so you can see the errors on app start-up).